# Loop through Joda Time months at month end

Tags: java, jodatime

I have created a loop with Joda Time to iterate through months and return dates based on a specified monthly frequency. The issue is that if today's date is end of month, the loop doesn't return my expected result. If I start on the 31st of July 2020, after a number of iterations I want to have returned 31st of July 2021, instead, it returns 30th of July 2020 (because previous month had only 30 days).

My code:

```
int frequency = 3;

for(LocalDate date = startDate; date.isBefore(endDate); date=date.plusMonths(frequency)  {
int date = Integer.parseInt(date.plusMonths(frequency).toString("yyyyMMdd"));
}
```

My expected outcome should be:
31 July 2020
31 Oct 2020
31 Jan 2021
30 April 2021
**31 July 2021**. But this code returns **30 July 2020**.

I also tried with this code, but no success:

```
Integer.parseInt(date.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue().plusMonths(frequency).toString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

How can I correctly iterate through month ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a minimal, runnable example, so I made some assumptions.

Here are the results of my test.

```
20200731
20201031
20210131
20210430
20210731
20211031
20220131
20220430
```

And here's the code I used to produce these results.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class MonthEnd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int frequency = 3;
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate endDate = startDate.plus(2, ChronoUnit.YEARS);

        for (LocalDate date = startDate; date.isBefore(endDate);
                date = date.plusMonths(frequency)) {
            LocalDate tdate = date.withDayOfMonth(date.lengthOfMonth());
            String dateString = tdate.format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
            int dateInt = Integer.parseInt(dateString);
            System.out.println(dateInt);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: These are the first four values that I get also, but the issue is on the fifth one, where instead of 20210731, i get 20210730.

Comment: @groogie13: See my updated answer.  You could have copied my code and ran this test yourself.